# Populating table using Indirect function and copying formula across the whole table

Tags: worksheet-function

Hi I am currently creating a budget and am stuck on the formulas i need to get the data on various worksheets pulled into specific sheets. I have created worksheets for Jan to Dec for my household expenditure and have also another worksheet which i intend to use as the summary sheet from which when i select a month will be populated by the data from months worksheet. I have managed to create a dropdown for selecting the months and use the indirect function INDIRECT(""&$E$3&"!E8") to get from a single cell. The challenge comes when i try to copy the formula on the rest of the cells to pull data from, it retains the same value.

How do i make it a dynamic formula so it becomes relative to the cell i have copied to whilst maintaining the dropdown selection for the months?

Another question is , i have also created a frequency dropdown with daily, weekly, monthly, etc. Which function can i use so that when i select for instance daily, the value enter in a cell will apply a function that multiplies it by 365/12 to give a monthly value.

Your help will greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `INDIRECT` formula is that you're using the dollar signs to fix the cell, which means when you drag the formula around it keeps pointing to the same cell. I'll explain a little bit more in depth below.

There are three options for cell references in Excel formulas: relative, fixed row, fixed column, and fixed row and column.

1. A **relative** cell reference (like `E3`), will change both the row and column when you drag or copy it around a worksheet. Say, for example, you put the formula `=B1` in the cell A2. If you drag that formula down one row (to cell A3), the formula in cell A3 will now be `=B2`. If, on the other hand, you drag right one column, to B2, the formula in B2 will now be `=C1`. Note that the formula in A2 stays the same in both of these instances.
2. A **fixed row** cell reference (`E$3`) will keep the row reference the same as you drag it around the worksheet. To use the example from above, dragging the formula `=B$1` in A2 down 1 row will result in `=B$1` in cell A3 -- the same thing as we had in A2! Dragging it to the right one cell, into B2, will result in `=C$1`, similar to the relative reference.
3. A **fixed column** reference (`$E3`) is just like a fixed row reference, except now the row is fixed. Dragging `=$B1` from A2 to A3 results in `=$B2` in cell A3. Dragging it to the right, however, will result in the same formula (`=$B1`) in cell B2.
4. A **fixed row and column** reference (probably not the official name, by the way) will combine the behavior from (2) and (3). If you put the formula `=$B$1` into cell A2, you can drag it up, down, left, or right and it will stay `=$B$1` no matter what.

Where you're going wrong with your formula is that you've used a **fixed row and column** reference when what you probably wanted was either a **fixed column** reference or a **relative** reference. Either one of those will result in changing the row being referenced as you drag the formula down your column.